# LINQ time subtraction in web api

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, rest, visual-studio-2015

I have created a 'WEB API' using 'MySQL'. Right now I am passing a `serial number` and a `date time` in the URL of API and get the expected result. Now I want to do is that when ever a request is sent. All the records are shown within `10 minutes` of `timespan`. i.e. If the time sent is `10/10/2017T3:15:00` then the data shown would be +5 and -5 minutes i.e. in between `3:10:00` to `3:20:00` providing the date should be the same.

To subtract the time `time.Subtract(...)` method can be used but I really don't know how to subtract and add the time and then get the result.

My controller code look like

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn, DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m=>(m.zdjh == msn)).Where(m=> (m.sjsj >= dt)).Select(m=> new { m.zdjh , m.sjsj, m.xhqd }).Distinct());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Note**

The adding and subtracting of time is dependent on the date time sent in the URL

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always 5 min before and after the provided Date, just use AddMinutes to add/remove from it. Something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn, DateTime dt)
{
    try
    {       
        var before = dt.AddMinutes(-5);
        var after = dt.AddMinutes(5);

        var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd
        .Where(m => 
            m.zdjh == msn &&
            m.sjsj >= before &&
            m.sjsj <= after)
        .Select(m=> new { m.zdjh , m.sjsj, m.xhqd }).Distinct());

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }
}
```

Note: I wouldn't hard code the 5 minutes there on a real application though. Usually this value would come from some  kind of configuration of your application. If you hard code the value like that and tomorrow the requirements change from 5 to 10 minutes, you have to compile and re deploy your app, which sucks. So keep that in mind.

Comment: Developer lesson 1: Don't trust others :)

Comment: Just for a thought, the API will be working using the client of `android` and `php` so would you suggest to take decision on client side ?

Comment: By decision you mean the date calculation? Dealing with dates/times is always tricky.. and it really depends on needs. One advice I would give though is if you are already not using.. use always UTC dates. Specially on apps that you don't really control where your users are coming from. This worth a read: https://blog.mojotech.com/the-complexity-of-time-data-programming/